# How to work out how powerful a motor needs to be to climb up a tube?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design

I am designing a device that can climb up a tube. To do so, I am planning to  use a motor that will utilize spinwheels with high friction.

How do I work out how powerful my motor needs to be?

The mass of the device is 1kg.

Comment: Jeremy Clarkson : " you can never have enough power"...

Comment: force (weight) times speed (how fast do you want it to climb?)

Comment: I tried to tune the formulation and English of your question, but I am not sure, if your English isn't better as mine. So feel free to fix it, if I actually worsened it on some points.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with agentp. Even a micro motor is enough power but will take long time to climb. The motor torque shall be designed to overcome load torque, off course.